# unnest_tokens does not convert I to i

Tags: r

When I use to_lower in unnest_tokens(), I is not converted to ı.
For examle, "In" is converted to "ın".
However if I use tolower(), "In" is converted to "in"

I used:
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
But nothing changed.

My operation system is Windows 10 (64) Turkish.

Does any one know the solution for my problem?
Best regards

Comment: Is it lower case L instead of upper case I

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could come up with lowering cases beforehand with `str_to_lower(text, locale = "en")`. In this case `stringr` package converts all capital "I"s correctly. Then you can use `unnest_tokens`.